# Plotly: How to set ticktext to italics?

Tags: python, fonts, plotly

I want to change the text style to italics for the text on axis ie. tickfont

Below is the relevant piece of script:

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# figure input
thing = ["apple","ball","cat"]
name = [1,2,3]
t = dict(family="Univers LT Std", size=14,color='black')

# figure setup
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=name, y=thing, type='scatter')])

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title="<i>Deviation from median (%)</i>",
                             titlefont=t, tickfont=t,gridcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)', showgrid=True))
fig.show()
```

**Plot:**

[image]

How do I change the text style of the text `apple, ball, cat` on the axis to italics without changing any other of the font property

Comment: Your snippet, as it was, raised a SyntaxError. I took the liberty to add some changes to make it run.

Comment: Thankyou for the updating my question @vestland hope this helps somebody else in future too :)

Comment: No problem! And yes, it most likely will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly allows some [HTML styling](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp) directly on the string input to your axis labels. And you can easily change `thing = ["apple","ball","cat"]` to `['<i>apple</i>', '<i>ball</i>', '<i>cat</i>']` using the list comprehension `thing = ['<i>'+elem+'</i>' for elem in thing]`

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

thing = ["apple","ball","cat"]
thing = ['<i>'+elem+'</i>' for elem in thing]

name = [1,2,3]
t = dict(family="Univers LT Std", size=14,color='black')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=name, y=thing, type='scatter')])

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title="<i>Deviation from median (%)</i>",
                             titlefont=t, tickfont=t,gridcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)', showgrid=True))
fig.show()
```